Dart infers type incorrectly
Dart infers type incorrectly with inheritance.
Dart type inference is not working properly with inheritance and field overriding.
If we don't explicitly write   final Dog pet = Dog(); (repetitive) the analyzer thinks that pet is Animal.  (which is not wrong but problematic, it should be Dog)
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {
  void bark() {
    print("Daawg!");
  }
}

abstract class Owner {
  Animal get pet;
}

class DogOwner extends Owner {
  @override
  final pet = Dog();
}

void main() {
  final dog = Dog();
  dog.bark(); // pass

  final owner = DogOwner();
  owner.pet.bark();  // error. Why ??
}

Is this a bug in Dart or intended ? I am curious to know why would this be intended.

Because Foo does not have boz method, neither the Bar

There was a typo. I fixed it, changed foo.boz() to foo.baz.boz(); in main

Boz is a Baz but Baz isn't a Boz,(names are confusing me )

I agree on that. However, we have  final baz = Boz();  in Foo . So Foo.baz should be a Boz  right ? Hence, why can't we do foo.baz.boz()

Yes, it was confusing. I changed all variables names to make it more clear

DogOwner.pet overrides Owner.pet, which returns an Animal. DogOwner.pet is inferred from the interface specified by Animal, not from the value it happens to be initialized with.  In general, you should specify types for non-local variables.

@jamesdlin,  Yes, what you described that is just the observed behavior is, which is what I observed too. The real question is: Is this intended ? Even the the best practice link you provided says "DO type annotate fields and top-level variables if the type isn't obvious" . Emphasizing on the if the type isn't obvious.  but the type in  final pet = Dog(); is obviously a Dog

It is not obvious in your example because it is an override.  IMO the observed behavior should be intended: the default behavior for an override should be to match the base interface, and if your intention is to return a narrower type, then that should be explicit.

In your original code, you were not explicitly overriding the getter. However, this approach is not wrong; it's  just a early days decision of Dart team.
When you declare final pet = Dog(); without specifying a type, Dart infers the type based on the context. In your case, since pet is overriding a getter that returns Animal, it infers the type as Animal.
Here's the correct way to override the getter:
class DogOwner extends Owner {
  @override
  Dog get pet => Dog();
}

void main() {
  final dog = Dog();
  dog.bark(); // pass

  final owner = DogOwner();
  owner.pet.bark();  // now it works
}


This is not related to the linked decision. There is no setter here, just one abstract getter, and it's overridden and implemented using a final field, which is perfectly reasonable.
The @override has no effect, it just silences a lint. The issue here is that final pet = Dog(); has no declared type, so a type is inferred. There are two options: The Pet of the getter it overrides, or the Dog of the value it is initialized to.
The language chooses the inherited type in this case, because that's consistent whether there is an initializer or not.

@Irn Thank you for the suggestion. I've refined my answer.
